# If $\ \frac{a^3+1}{a} = \frac{b^3+1}{b} = \frac{c^3+1}{c} $ find $\ a^3+b^3+c^3 $ if a,b and c are distinct

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, roots, problem-solving

I know that this question can be solved using Vieta's relations somehow but I don't know how. I tried solving it with basic algebra but to no avail. I tried to make an equation with roots a,b and c but I didn't get anywhere with that either.

I cross multiplied the first two equations and did some factoring to get $(a-b)[ab(a+b)-1] = 0.$ Hence, $a=b$ or $ab(a+b)=1.$

I also tried making an equation $x^3 -px^2 +qx -r=0$ with roots a,b and c. But my attempts reached dead ends. I'd love to see your solution.

Comment: Various solutions on AoPS: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5C%20%5Cfrac%7Ba%5E3%2B1%7D%7Ba%7D%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7Bb%5E3%2B1%7D%7Bb%7D%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7Bc%5E3%2B1%7D%7Bc%7D%24&p=1

Comment: The numbers $a,b,c$ could simply be equal to each other, so $a^3+b^3+c^3$ could be anything

Comment: Is there a condition missing here? As it stands I can choose $a=b=c\neq 0$ and get any non-zero sum I like.

Comment: I thought of a=b=c, but the YouTube video from where I got the question doesn't state any other conditions.

Comment: It likely requires distinct values, and that just wasn't conveyed clearly enough.

Comment: For non-trivial solutions, $a^3+b^3+c^3=-3$

Comment: @Sujal Motagi I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts. There is a very nice solution.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg I cross multiplied the first two equations and did some factoring to get (a-b)[ab(a+b)-1] = 0. Hence, a=b or ab(a+b)=1. I also tried making an equation x^3 -px^2 +qx -r=0 with roots a,b and c. But my attempts reached dead ends. I'd love to see your solution.

Comment: @Sujal Motagi Wait please. We need to open this topic. It takes time.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg Oh okay, I thought you wanted me to just write it in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got that $$ab(a+b)=1.$$
By the same way:$$ac(a+c)=1$$ and $$bc(b+c)=1.$$
Thus, $$ab(a+b)=ac(a+c)$$ or
$$ab+b^2-ac-c^2=0$$ or
$$a(b-c)+(b-c)(b+c)=0$$ or
$$(b-c)(a+b+c)=0$$ or
$$a+b+c=0.$$
Note that b and c are distinct, so dividing by (b-c) is valid as $b-c≠0$
Id est, $$a^3+b^3+c^3=a^3+b^3-(a+b)^3=-3ab(a+b)=-3.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $a, b, c$ are the three distinct roots to $ x^3 - k x + 1 = 0$.

> So $ a+b+c = 0, ab+bc+ca = -k, abc = -1$ from Vietas.
>  There are a few ways to complete this from here.

Comment: I did try something similar, but aren't you assuming that a+b+c=0 and abc=1 by doing this?

Comment: That follows from Vieta's formulas.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, if you consider the above equation then by Vieta's formulas the sum of roots must be 0. But we don't know that about a,b and c.

Comment: (Assuming that they are distinct) $a, b, c$ are roots of the cubic. What do you mean by "But we don't know that about a,b and c"?

Comment: How do you know that a+b+c=0? It's not in the question.

Comment: Let me repeat myself. 1) $a, b, c$ are roots of $x^3-kx+1 = 0$. 2) By vieta, we know that the sum of the roots are 0. 3) Hence, $ a  + b + c = 0$. Now, which of these statements are confusing to you?

Comment: You are just creating an equation such that a+b+c=0, how can you do that?

Comment: Please stop ignoring me. Which of my three statements is confusing to you? 1), 2) or 3)?

Comment: @SujalMotagi, he is not talking about the question's $a,b,c$ in the form you want, he is deducing the relationship using vieta's